# Different popOvers for Multiple Dynamically Added Selectors with Bootstrap3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am looking to generate multiple selectors via Javascript, each with their own popOver content, which is also dynamically added with Javascript.

How do you get two or more to work?

```
$(function()
{           
    $('body').popover({
        selector: '[rel=popOver1]',
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: 'contents1',
        html: true
    });

    $('body').popover({
        selector: '[rel=popOver2]',
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: 'contents2',
        html: true
    });
});


$('<p><a class="btn" rel="popOver1">popOver1</a></p>').appendTo('.buttons');

$('<p><a class="btn" rel="popOver2">popOver2</a></p>').appendTo('.buttons');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to @JasonP answering a follow-up question with this comment:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/EdBc8/

### Javascript

```
function createPopOver(selector, content) {
    $(selector).popover({
        //selector: selector,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'right',
        content: content,
        html: true
    });
}

function addBtn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        $('.buttons').append("<p><a class='btn' rel='popOver" + i + "'>popOver" + i + "</a></p>");

        createPopOver('[rel="popOver' + i + '"]', "content for " + i);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">   </div>
```